# Normalizing constant of mixture of dirichlet distribution goes unbounded

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, probability, dirichlet

I need to calculate PDFs of mixture of Dirichlet distribution in python. But for each mixture component there is the normalizing constant, which is the inverse beta function which has gamma function of sum of the hyper-parameters as the numerator. So even for a sum of hyper-parameters of size '60' it goes unbounded. Please suggest me a work around for this problem. What happens when I ignore the normalizing constant?

First its not the calculation of NC itself that is the problem. For a single dirichlet I have no problem . But what I have here is a mixture of product of dirichlets, so each mixture component is a product of many dirichlets each with its own NCs. So the product of these goes unbounded. Regarding my objective, I have a joint distribution of p(s,T,O), where 's' is discrete, 'T' and 'O' are the dirichlet variables i.e. a set of vectors of parameters which sum to '1'. Now since 's' is discrete and finite I have |S| set of mixture of product of dirichlet components for each 's'. Now my objective here is to find p(s|T,O). So I directly substitute a particular (T,O) and calculate the value of each p('s'|T,O). For this I need to calc the NCs. If there is only one mixture component then I can ignore the norm constant, calc. and renormalise finally, but since I have several mixture components each components will have different scaling and so I can't renormalise. This is my conundrum.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas. (1) To calculate the normalizing factor exactly, maybe you can rewrite the gamma function via gamma(a_i + 1) = a_i gamma(a_i) (a_i need not be an integer, let the base case be a_i < 1) and then you'll have sum(a_i, i, 1, n) terms in the numerator and denominator and you can reorder them so that you divide the largest term by the largest term and multiply those single ratios together instead of computing an enormous numerator and an enormous denominator and dividing those. (2) If you don't need to be exact, maybe you can apply Stirling's approximation. (3) Maybe you don't need the pdf at all. For some purposes, you just need a function which is proportional to the pdf. I believe Markov chain Monte Carlo is like that. So, what is the larger goal you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have edited the question for explaining in detail. Please specify if you need any additional details

Comment: OK. From your new comments, it appears (3) is ruled out. So my advice is to try (2) first and see if the approximation is close enough, otherwise (1). Maybe you can figure out (depending on the magnitude of the argument) how to switch automatically from (2) to (1).